# Scrape Table Data into .csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am able to print out the table, but not able to extract the same into a .csv file. I am new to scraping and learning every day.

How can I screen-scrape this data to a CSV file?

The standard library modules
    import os
    import sys

```
# The wget module
import wget

# The BeautifulSoup module
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# The selenium module
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # if you want to use chrome, replace Firefox()    with Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.arcountydata.com/county.asp?county=Benton") # load the web page
search_begin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Assessor']/div/div[2]/a/i").click()
# for websites that need you to login to access the information
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("OwnerName") # Find the email input field of the login form
elem.send_keys("Roth Family Inc") # Send the users email

search_exeute = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Search']").click()


src = driver.page_source # gets the html source of the page

parser = BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml") # initialize the parser and parse the source "src"


table = parser.find("table", attrs={"class" : "table table-striped-yellow     table-hover table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive"}) # A list of attributes that you want to check in a tag)

f = open('/output.csv', 'w')

parcel=""
owner=""
ptype=""
site_address=""
location=""
acres=""

summons =[]
#print table

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace("&nbsp;", "")
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
print list_of_rows

driver.close() # closes the driver ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Very nice to see a new member, Good luck to you fine Sir!
You're doing an awesome job, you commented your code very nicely, meaning you understand it, great job!

```
import csv
```

This is a module in python that allows easy reading/writing CSV files, so let's import that first.

```
  with open(name_csv+'.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
      spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
      spamwriter.writerow(list_of_rows)
#Used to write 1 row, each element in the array will be seperated by a comma
```

EDIT:

```
with open('somecsv.csv','w+') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|') # Changed the delimiter (Way of separating )
    # This opens the CSV file and we set some additional parameters
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[::2]:
        list_of_cell = []
        for cell in row.findAll('td')[:5]:
            text = cell.text.replace("&nbsp;", "").strip()
            text = text.replace('''...\n\n\n'''," |") #This one is added so it replaces string before Lot with comma
            text = text.replace(''':\n''',':') #This one is added so it doesn't interfere
            text = text.replace('''\n''','|') #Adds a comma before block
            list_of_cell.append(text)
        print(list_of_cell)
        spamwriter.writerow(list_of_cell)
```

Comment: Thanks Faulty.. It helps as I am able to parse the data to csv now. However the entire data get parsed into 1 row.. what should I do so that it parses row by row as evident in html table...

Comment: This should work, don't forget to import csv. I'll look to add selenction  Selenium too.

Comment: Thank You very much sir.. It helps me learn something new today..  I will try to scrub the code further...for some data is a column that is parsed in multiple rows..

Comment: am i missing something.. the output file in csv is introducing blank rows for values in "location' field within the html table

Comment: Oh, there's an issue, I found out that there is another TR within the TR that's why there are blank spaces

Comment: There you go user, it should be a little bit more intuitive to play with now :), I changed the delimiter, it's not comma separated, it's | separated :)

Comment: Thank you sir.. I learnt some new things today.. appreciate the help.

Comment: No worries, make sure to mark my answer as (THE ANSWER) if it was the correct one, so don't forget to leave feedback for future stackoverflowers.
I just wanted to add [::2] is the step so lets say we have a=[1,2,3,4] and the we print(print[::2]) output: 1,3.
Meaning it will jump for 2 indexses. Skipping the one in your case the redundant tr